Should I include my prologue in my query as a sample chapter/sample pages?
I am currently querying agents for a novel that has a prologue. A lot of literary agents ask for sample chapters (three, for example). Should I send the prologue and the first two chapters, the prologue and the first three chapters, or not send the prologue at all? I suppose having the prologue there isn't crucial, but it's nice to have that backround information, and it acts like a sort of hook for readers.

I cannot count the number of times I have been told by professional readers and agents and consultants that prologues are poison for your chances of getting published, but it is many.
Unless your prologue is in the form of a short story, prologues are "telling" not "showing". In modern fiction it seldom "works" and is seldom a "hook".
The first chapter of the first Harry Potter is effectively a prologue in the form of a story, introducing the world of magic early so the reader is not misled by the lack of magic in what used to be Chapter 1. If possible, make your prologue part of the story.

If the agent or publisher requires you to send the first three chapters, you must include the prologue. Consider it as a chapter, unless it is much shorter than the other chapters.
As for your assessment that "having the prologue there isn't crucial" – of course it is! That is the beginning of your book and that is what either hooks or repels your readers. Many readers disklike prologues, while others (in certain genres) enjoy them tremendously. It can be a selling point or a flaw, especially if badly executed. If agents or publishers want to read the beginning of your book, they want to read the prologue, if there is one. So make sure you include it.
If the agent or publisher requires you to send three chapters from anywhere in the book, you may send whichever three chapters you want.

Thanks you for answering! My main issue is that, like the person who commented on my question said, some agents might dismiss a query with a prologue as bad and automatically throw it away. While my prologue doesn't info-dump, it's also only two pages long, which wouldn't be considered a chapter. If I do add the prologue to my sample pages, should I also include the first three chapters (in my example of the agent asking for the first three chapters), or have the prologue and only two chapters?

@IzzyE.Stewart (1) As I said in my answer, if the prologue has the length of a chapter, send the prologue and the first two chapters. Technically, the prologue is a chapter. The first 3 chapters = Prologue, Chapter 1, Chapter 2. Or inquire with the agent or publisher before you submit. (2) Many readers – and therefore many agents and publishers – dislike prologues. If you don't want to turn off those readers, write a story without prologue. But if you have one, do submit it, if the agent or publisher wants to read the beginning of your text. The prologue is the beginning, if there is one.
